# Is there a way to decorate an int property so that it serializes as a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, json.net

Is it possible to create a decorator for a property of a class of type int so it serializes as a string?

I have

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        [SerializeAsString] //this is what I want
        public int StreetCode { get; set; }
    }
```

so when I call

```
var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass);
```

I want it to output the value between quotes rather than as an int without quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This requires a custom converter based on Newtonsoft.Json.Converter to be created.

Then you would use the converter like so

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ToStringConverter))]
public int StreetCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: More info at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm, example implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354867/how-to-make-json-net-serializer-to-call-tostring-when-serializing-a-particular