Correct way to create a Version object from string such that it can easily be serialised / deserialised
Consider the following line of C# code:
ProtocolVersion = new Version("6.10.7011");

So that parses the string and creates the object no problem, however it sets the Revision to -1 by default..
If I then serialise this using Newtonsoft.Json I get this:
  "ProtocolVersion": {
    "Major": 6,
    "Minor": 10,
    "Build": 7011,
    "Revision": -1,
    "MajorRevision": -1,
    "MinorRevision": -1
  }

When I later try to deserialise it, it takes issue with the negative numbers in the revisions.

'Version's parameters must be greater than or equal to zero. Parameter name: revision'

Revision is read-only so I can't just assign it or provide it in the constructor (because it doesn't go with the string). Now I could of course append ".0" to the initial version string but I don't know in advance how many parts it could be - could be "6" or "6.10" or "6.10.7011" - so I have to write code to detect that, which seems rather inelegant.
This is my current solution...
string versionSuffix = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(".0", Math.Max(0, 3 - versionString.Count(v => v == '.'))));
ProtocolVersion = new Version($"{versionString}{versionSuffix}"); 

Is there a 'correct' way to handle this?

I would serialize the version as string. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22355712/880990 shows an approach using a JsonConverter (it shows only the conversion from object to string but the reverse operation is straight forward to implement).

Does Parsing Version type with Json.NET during deserialization throws an error answer your question?  It shows a converter that handles both strings and objects during deserialization, and optionally serializes as a string or object depending on an argument.  Do note that Json.NET serializes Version inconsistently between .NET Framework and .NET Core.

I would implement such utility method, which is more readable in my opinion:
public static Version GetCompleteVersion(string version)
{
    var v = new Version(version);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(Math.Max(v.Major, 0));
    sb.Append('.');
    sb.Append(Math.Max(v.Minor, 0));
    sb.Append('.');
    sb.Append(Math.Max(v.Build, 0));
    sb.Append('.');
    sb.Append(Math.Max(v.Revision, 0));
    return new Version(sb.ToString());
}

